# How to extinguish humanity in late 15th century?

Tags: medieval, death

*Warning:* this question involves an evil plot to kill all humanity, and it could be disturbing for some people.

Suppose a humanoid being indistinguishible from an adult human appears in the late 15th century with this evil plan: to extinguish humanity. He has some unusual abilities:

**- He can't be killed:** he is invulnerable to physical damage, but he is not immortal, as he ages and have a lifespan comparable to a human being.

**- He has a powerful weapon:** he is able to yield a personal sword-like weapon that can defeat enemies with ease. It could be compared with a lightsaber in terms of destructive power.

**- He can communicate well:** he is able to speak the language of the people in the place he first appears (Chinese if in China; Old English if in England, and so on) and learns fast.

According to studies, the human population at this time was between 400 and 540 million. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimates_of_historical_world_population).

So he couldn't just get his sword and kill them one by one, because this would require 40 years and 1 killed per second (10 hours of killing per day). His strategies would probably involve war, famine and disease, not just death directly.

**The question is: which strategy would he adopt in order to achieve his goal during his lifespan on Earth** (40 years from his first appearance)**?**

Comment: Somewhat broad, story based and opinion based (fishing for ideas). If you could find a way to ask which isn't any of those, that would be great.

Comment: Humans are (relatively) clever. Sooner or later, they're going to catch on. They'll just fashion a trap and catch him while he's sleeping or pooping or shagging. Take his weapon and toss him into the oubliette. Problem solved.  What kinds of plans or abilities does your guy have for overcoming a large mass of determined foes?

Comment: Rrright... does he fly? Because, you know, Australia and a good bunch of Pacific islands. As a measure of population isolation/contact, the number of Aboriginal languages in Australia is [around 290–363](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Aboriginal_languages). Letting aside the tribes of people in the Amazon jungle and in central/south Africa.

Comment: By the term  late 15th century, I am assuming the period 1450 to 1499. If so, you have a very big problem. Some obscure person, Chris Columbus, found a new land, that became America, that was given the absolute right, by God, to be the greatest nation on earth. Can't fight God's decree, no matter how powerful he (it) is. You would have to do it early 1400's, before anyone established a settlement in America.

Comment: when "The Master" show up on earth that's generally his aim but he has a longer lifespan. and so plays a longer game https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_(Doctor_Who)

Comment: why not follow what genghis khan already do? minus doing the 1 in 200 men is his descendant thing, just litter a bunch of corpse,poop,rats or other vermin every place with high population including to the public bath (especially to eastern europe and middle east) and water reservoir  to create more bubonic plague and black death and send plague ship to spread it to other island

Comment: even native american lost major population just from getting the european sickness after their first contact (excluding their early encounter with scandinavian) due to them doesnt have the immunity to the plague europe encounter before.

Comment: oh yeah also burn their farms and kill their healthy livestock to make sure they wont be able to survive, the rest is kill the plague doctor and marker and maybe kill the one that develop immunity to make sure they cant recover even under quarantine, so they either starve to death or embrace the nurgle.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that, with what we are given in the question, he is probably out of luck. Complete extinction is barely possible now with global travel and advanced technology. Take away 500 years of development and almost all possibilities vanish. Even if the humanoid had knowledge of technology comparable to what is available today, the lack of infrastructure would be a major and probably insurmountable problem. Of course, one could assume that the humanoid has a spaceship with a fully-equipped-lab/machine-shop/magic-factory that washes away all of the difficulties, but that rather takes all of the fun out of world building, at least for me.

The question is incomplete. In engineering terms, it would seem that you have a solution (the specifics regarding the humanoid) in search of a problem. Why the hostility? What does the humanoid hope to achieve by such an extinction? What would come after the extinction? Where did the humanoid come from? What motivation does the humanoid have? Does the humanoid have masters? What do they want? In short, what is the humanoid's story?

I like world building. The challenge in world building is to create something with internal consistency. That means that it makes sense right now in terms of motivation, economics, belief systems, and social structures. It also means that the constructed world has a past that is equally sensible. Ditto the future. The key is on-going sustainability. This is true for realistic world building as well as for fantasy world building.  I find worlds that disregard this fundamental requirement to be mere hand waving and thus deeply unsatisfying.

What we have here is a premise. I was looking for a story that grew from that premise. I did not find it. This is a poor, opinion-heavy answer but it is the best that I can do, given what the question was.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a modern-day knowledge, his best bet would be to engineer a disease by selecting and roughly mutating strains of *Y. Pestis* or *Variola major*, both already present in the 15th century.

But this would not be guaranteed to extinguish the *whole* of humanity, also because a large part of that humanity is not significantly connected with the main body. He has to reach the Far East, and more than that, the Americas ([Thor Heyerdahl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_Heyerdahl) demonstrated that this is possible).

So what he does is use his invulnerability and powerful weapon (not to mention superior knowledge) to establish himself as *the central figure of a death cult*. Many cults have flourished with their originators never being able to show any actual *proof* of their teachings. He, on the other hand, has the knowledge and the means to impersonate, for instance, Yaldabaoth the Demiurge, or a messenger thereof.

By carefully tuning the teachings and rituals of his followers, he can get death squads sworn to scouring the Earth, with weapons and disease, and ensure they too will ultimately estinguish themselves once their task is done (just for example, they have to segregate women and can only sire children if they have killed a given number of unbelievers).

Answer (score 1):

The problem he has in 15th century earth is his inability to travel far. Humanity is too spread out in small villages to allow a plague to spread far and wide, IIRC, during that period. That is assuming he can engineer such a plague with tech then.

It may be possible to equip / teach one group of invaders so they take over, but that would just lead to large reduction, not extinction.

You may have to combine the two... Use one group to kill everyone else, then kill that group with some sort of plague / bio-weapon.